# is it right sentence or not..? "What we mean by smart devices are smartphones"

Tags: sentence-structure, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number, sentence-choice, run-on-sentences

What we mean by smart devices **are** smartphones, tablets and Ipads and we mean by young adults are girls and boys around 20 to 30.

Is it a right sentence or not...? Do I have to use "are" or "is"?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to say.  20 -year olds might be considered "young adults" but not usually 30-year olds.  Could you please add more detail to your question?

Comment: I'm sorry but we don't proofread here. If you explain what specifically you think is wrong with the sentence, we can address that but, as written, this question is off topic and likely to be closed.

Comment: If you think *smart devices* is plural, then you must use **are**, if you think *smart devices* is singular, then you must use **is**.

Comment: To this US English speaker, only **is** sounds appropriate.  I think this is because the verb actually refers to "What we mean", not to "smartphones".

Answer (score 1):

You can rephrase to avoid the difficult syntax:

> By "smart devices" we mean smartphones, tablets and iPads.

This makes the subject "we" and "mean" is the main verb, so the agreement is simple. n the example you give, the paraphrase is shorter, tighter and easier to form.

It may be necessary to use "What we mean..." in some situations, for example: "What he means by 'smartphones' is unclear." this is a singular noun phrase, and the verb form would be "is". Even this might be better put into a passive form: "It is unclear what he means by 'smartphones'."

Note that the word being defined is quoted, to make the "use/mention" distinction clear.

Note someone in their 20s or 30s would not normally be considered to be a girl or boy. Try "By 'young adult' we mean someone in their 20s or 30s." Again, by rephrasing I have avoided difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

**Hello**, sir.

> What we mean by smart devices

That whole clause is called: **Noun Clause**, accompanied of one *adverbial modifier*: **by smart devices**.

I, particularly, have never seen a **Noun Clause** precede a plural verb, its agreement with the verb is always **singular**, even if the following terms are plural.

Check this example:

> **What I did yesterday** ''doesn't'' matter

I may have done many things; however, the verb is always singular "**doesn't**" and not "**don't**".

Nonetheless, I don't discard the possibility of using a plural verb in such sentences:

> **What I like** "are" toys
>
> **What you wanted in the party** "were" cakes

For two reasons: If you invert the placement of the whole clause, you get:

> **Cakes** "were" what you wanted.
>
> **Toys** "were" what you liked.

And since "**What**" is an abstract thing, i.e: it can refer to countless things, it might be possible to say:

> What we mean by smart devices **are** smartphones, tablets and Ipads